# How to delete/block a list of users contained in a CSV file?

Tags: users, advertising

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to delete/block users from a CSV file.

**Here is more information of the solution that I'm looking for:**

I have a CSV with a list of users that are spam or not responding to emails. I would take that list and give it to a Drupal module and corresponding delete or block or make inactive users.

Ideally, it would work like logintoboggan:

- Disable the account and keep its content.
- Disable the account and unpublish its content.
- Delete the account and make its content belong to the Anonymous user.
- Delete the account and its content."

User should be able to set that for the batch.

How can I achieve this? If there is a module that can take me to a similar direction, that would be fine too.

Answer (score 6):

You really don't need a CSV; all you need is the identifying column (e.g. `mail` or `uid`). To that end, you have one option  with the [Bulk User Delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/userdelete) module.

> This module allows you to bulk delete users through the admin
>   interface. You provide a list of email addresses, one per line, and
>   the users are deleted using the batch processing API.

With this module, you can grab your mail column to feed into the interface to bulk delete.

Answer (score 5):

As [Shawn Conn](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/45675/shawn-conn) said, the Bulk User Delete module seems like it would work. If you're looking for more of a one time quick-and-dirty solution, you could accomplish it with a shell script and Drush like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read username; do
  drush user-cancel $username
done < list_of_usernames.txt
```

See http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-7x/user/user-cancel for more info on that Drush command.